# Is there anyway I could remove the parentheses from a tuple in a list and the commas?

Tags: python

Let's say I had some code like this:

```
import itertools

listone = list(itertools.permutations([1,2],2))
```

The output would be :

```
[(1,2),(2,1)]
```

Is there anything I could add to my code to make the output:

```
[12,21]
```

Comment: `[int(''.join(map(str, t))) for t in listone]` will do that but why? Are you sure this is not an XY problem?

Comment: You can use `.join()` on any iterable, tuples included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, assuming that the each of the numbers is a solution to `0 <= n < 10` and that the first number in the tuple is a solution to `n != 0` then the following is reversible:

```
>>> [int(''.join(str(e) for e in t)) for t in [(1,2),(2,1)]]
[12, 21]
>>> [tuple(int(e) for e in str(t)) for t in [12, 21]]
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

But this is most likely not that useful

Comment: What are the solutions for `n` in `0 <= n < 10` where `n` is an `int`. They are `range(10)` i.e. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: Consider `[(30,2),(2,30)]` where `1` was replaced with `30`. This is turned into `[302, 230]` but reversing it results in `[(3, 0, 2), (2, 3, 0)]`. As `[(30,2),(2,30)] != [(3, 0, 2), (2, 3, 0)]` these two are not inverses when n is outside the range.

Comment: Thank you! I don't need to reverse it so it's fine.